# Why does a history tracking report not show any records for a particular user?

Tags: reporting, history-tracking, field-history

Two users with the same security settings/roles do not get the same records in a history tracking report (they have access to the same records). More specifically; one of them does not see any records at all.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the values in the Field/Event field (history tracking specific) change based on the user language settings. This resulted in a report filter that stopped working (the filter value was in different language than the user was using).

E.g. Someone with English language settings is creating a report using the using the following filter: < Case record type = 'Complaint' > 
Someone with Dutch language settings would have the Case record type be translated from 'Complaint' to 'Klacht' in Dutch. Thus the field values would contain 'Klacht' but the report would still be filtering on 'Complaint'. Thus, this would result in 0 records being visible.